# Writing a script to automatically select and pick a hero in dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

I know that you can modify a lot in dota 2. I heard that the spinning wheel when you select your hero at the beginning can be modified to start at the hero you want. 
So is there a script which automatically picks my favourite hero ?

Comment: From my experience, I think the spinning wheel (by default) starts at the last hero you played. A non-script solution is clearly just to play one hero. Forever. :P

Comment: for me it's starts always at the same hero and i play different ones.

Comment: Hmm, actually, I think some of the time it starts at Abaddon (the earliest hero, alphabetically), and some of the time the hero I was assigned in All Random. You could always pick them in grid view, or just type their name.

Comment: yes but I dont want to type in like all the others I want to pick first. :)

Comment: I think there's a console command to choose a hero by ID number, just don't know what it is.

Comment: that would be cool

Comment: @RayofCommand Related to your other question, you might also find [this](http://twop.navi-gaming.com/en/dota_2/gameplay/Console_commands#11) useful.

Answer (score 2):

Right in the beginning, where the **Hero Chosing Wheel** is showing up, **you can type your heroes' name into it.**

The typed letters will be shown and the wheel spins to the next hero with these letters in the beginning of his name.

So if you want to play **Lion** for example, you can just input "**lio**" and have him in front of you.

Comment: sorry but that's not what I am looking for. Still li will show me lich and lina before lion ;)? I want a script to pick

Comment: Added an O to Lio. :) Well I'm not sure if automated scripts are even allowed per terms. Someone else has to help. :)

Comment: Is it possible to bind typing a hero name and then enter to a button using the bind console command?

Comment: Something like changing the default hero grid layout and removing all heroes but one should be possible I think ? Then you would just have to press Enter

Comment: Furthermore you could mark your desired hero as favorite pregame and set the filter to only show your favorite heroes

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Click the little star at the top right of the hero card to set it as favorite.

Answer (score 2):

You can have the game autoscroll to a specific hero using the `dota_set_avatar x` config setting. x corresponds to the hero's id number, which can be found in the game files. You can't automatically select the hero in any way that I've found.

Comment: this command is not listed here: http://dota2.gamepedia.com/List_of_Console_Commands is this command new? The page was last updated on 22 May. PS: there might be commands to select the hero too. Will try some stuff at home